# I can't get the UI to draw before advancing to next activity

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

When I run this, It is supposed to draw the ui, (two simple images and a text static text field) wait five seconds, then advance to the next activity (another page with a few buttons)

I can get it to load the images and not advance, OR to show a blank page, wait five, then go forward.

The main java doc:

```
package com.example.ccbc_maps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //When I add a call to the main function here it just displays the white space
        //Then advances after five seconds same thing if I paste the code within
        //The main method.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
     }

    public void main()
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {

        }

        Intent goForward = new Intent(this, CampusSelect.class);
        startActivity(goForward);
    }
}
```

And this is the class it advances to:

```
package com.example.ccbc_maps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class CampusSelect extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_campus_select);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_campus_select, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Good job formatting your first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are not working as you expect because you're forcing the main thread (UI thread) to sleep.

When you modify the UI, like call `setContentView()` or modify the properties of your Views, they do not happen immediately. Instead, they get put in a message queue to be executed by the main thread later.

You need to actually do the waiting in a separate thread. Probably the simplest way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to use [Handler.postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) to schedule some work to be done on the main thread at a later time.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.R.layout.activity_main);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Intent goForward = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CampusSelect.class);
            startActivity(goForward);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
When I added that code to my program it returns this error: (On the line which defines the new intent)
"The constructor Intent(new Runnable(){}, Class<CampusSelect>) is 
 undefined"

Comment: @user1827779 Changing `this` to `MainActivity.this` should correct that. Since it's in an anonymous inner class, the `this` is pointing to the instance of the runnable you're defining, and not the Activity context.

Comment: Yeah my bad, didn't actually compile my answer, it should read `new Intent(MainActivity.this, CampusSelect.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your activity is visible only onCreate() method is finished